# What to do with overlapping spring boot starters

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

We have a pretty large codebase developed on Spring Boot and over the course of time, we have kept adding starters as required. I am going through a bit of housekeeping and have noticed that there are quite a bit of overlap in the dependencies provided by the starters. For eg. for creating a REST API, we started out with the `spring-boot-starter-web` and later added `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`. But I just noticed that `spring-boot-starter-web` is a direct dependency of `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`.

Now I know that as a best practice, if my code is using a library directly, that library should always be a direct dependency instead of relying on another library depending on it. But Spring Boot starters are just a BOM so I am wondering if there is a better practice here.

Comment: This is entirely up to you. I personally tend to try to prune them unless I need to have a dependency listed to force a newer version, but that's just for general tidiness. The BOMiness doesn't really matter.